# Как правильно перенести блок div внутри шаблона Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, вёрстка, css3, bootstrap

Есть шаблон page.php моего сайта на Wordpress:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сайт: http://lagaro-wordpress-bootstrap.byethost33.com/

Как перенести  в указанное на картинке место, и растянуть на всю ширину блока  ?

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all pages.
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a
 * different template.
 *
 * @package _tk
 */

get_header(); ?>

<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

                <?php
                        // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
                        if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() )
                                comments_template();
                ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>



<div class="custom">
        <p><span style="font-size: 10.5pt; line-height: 115%; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #3bab4e; " lang="NL-BE">Quazr bvba&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;| Rue des Fusilles 5 | B-7750 Mont de | &prime;Enclus | T <a href="tel:+32 (0)69 23 50 23">+32 (0)69 23 50 23</a> | F <a href="tel:+32 (0)69 23 60 23">+32 (0)69 23 60 23</a></p></div>

      </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Код шаблона здесь: http://pastebin.com/cbXEtnZX

Comment: код нужно обязательно включать в сам вопрос. Для форматирования кода есть специальные кнопки в редакторе. )

Comment: Я нажимал кнопку "код", но код вставлялся почему-то не весь.

Comment: странно. Проверьте, сейчас весь? Вы можете нажать [править] и посмотреть, как выглядит разметка.

Comment: Ну сейчас-то все ок. Просто вставить опять - все сломать не хочу.

Comment: Вы кинули кусок контроллера, а не шаблона.

Comment: Что значит контроллер? Что это?

Answer (score 2):

У вас в исходном коде готовой страницы следующее сейчас:

```
            </div><!-- close .*-inner (main-content or sidebar, depending if sidebar is used) -->
        <div class="custom">
<p><span style="font-size: 10.5pt; line-height: 115%; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #3bab4e; " lang="NL-BE">Quazr bvba&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;| Rue des Fusilles 5 | B-7750 Mont de | ′Enclus | T <a href="tel:+32 (0)69 23 50 23">+32 (0)69 23 50 23</a> | F <a href="tel:+32 (0)69 23 60 23">+32 (0)69 23 60 23</a></p></div>
        </div><!-- close .row -->
    </div><!-- close .container -->
</div><!-- close .main-content -->

<footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
```

ваш код

`<div class="custom"> ... </div>`

нужно разместить между `</div><!-- close .row -->` и `</div><!-- close .container -->`

Вам нужно найти в шаблоне где формируются эти строки, ну а дальше по ситуации.